# Can this ground loop potentially damage my laptop or equipment?

Tags: pcb

From my research by the internet, they said that a ground loop can be eliminated by just plugging your devices into one AC source with the same ground. You will reduce the difference in electrical potential between grounds of the devices.

I'm not quite sure that I understand correctly.

[image]

Comment: what is your understanding?

Comment: by having different path of ground, can lead to difference potential of devices which will damage your devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's actually how you create ground loops. When all devices are isolated and only have one suppy and return path, then there cannot be any ground loops.

It really depends on equipment. You likely have at least one loop, from outlet via laptop to oscilloscope and back to outlet. Assuming laptop ground is earth referenced. Another potential loop is via outlet to power supply and back through laptop or oscilloscope to outlet.

You need to be sure if laptop and power supply are isolated or not for further analysis.

The problem with ground loops is that if your DUT consumes say 10A from power supply, if the ground  connection between supply and DUT breaks, 10A can flow via other routes through other ground connections like via oscilloscope or laptop and their wiring is not meant to handle that.